# Merge two subversion repositories

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a sad situation where my subversion repository got accidentally corrupted. Now I have two repositories and I'd like to merge into one

The first one has histories 1-20,24-207,235-312
The second has histories 1-257,

How can I merge these into one repo going 1-312?

These are otherwise identical repositories because one is a backup of the other.
I'm using svn 1.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the process will be:
From the corrupt repo:

```
svnadmin dump -r258:312 > dumpfile
```

In the dated but uncorrupted repo:

```
svnadmin load < dumpfile
```

At which point the uncorrupted repo will have everything.

See [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) for more information and potential tweaks/tuning to make the process smoother.